# On a property of equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm trying to prove that if $\mathcal{R}$ is an equivalence relation over $E$ and if $y\in Cl(x)$, $x,y\in E$ then we have $Cl(y)=Cl(x)$.

We will proceed by double inclusion. Let $a\in Cl(y)\Rightarrow a\in E$. We can write $a\mathcal{R}y$. Because $y\in Cl(x)$ we have $y\mathcal{R}x$. Because of the transitive nature of $\mathcal{R}$ we consequently have $a\mathcal{R}x\Rightarrow a\in Cl(x)$. Hence $Cl(y)\subseteq Cl(x)$.

Now let $a\in Cl(x)\Rightarrow a\in E$. We can write $a\mathcal{R}x$. Because of the reflexive nature of $\mathcal{R}$ $y\mathcal{R}x\Rightarrow x\mathcal{R}y$. Hence because of the transitive nature of $\mathcal{R}$ we have $a\mathcal{R} y$. Consequently $Cl(x)\subseteq Cl(y)$.

To conclude we have  $Cl(x)\subseteq Cl(y)$ and  $Cl(y)\subseteq Cl(x)$ so $Cl(x)=Cl(y)$.

My only doubt as to whether this proof is valid or not stems from the implication in the second part of the proof; because $x\mathcal{R}y\Rightarrow y\mathcal{R}x$ is an implication is the proof valid?

Comment: I don't know what the point of saying $a\in Cl(y)\implies a\in E$ is.  $Cl(y)$, presumably, means the set of elements $b\in E$ such that $y\sim_R b$, right?  We're only talking about elements in $E$ here.

Comment: Yes, it's just an attempt at being extra clear.

Comment: I think it makes things less clear.  You keep saying "Let" that claim be true, which suggests that it might not be, and that therefore your argument would be incomplete.  I'd leave that off.

Comment: Other than that redundancy, I think the argument is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\cal R$ be an equivalence relation over $E$. Reflexivity means that for all $a \in E$, you have $a \cal R a.$ On the other hand, symmetry tells you that for each pair $a,b \in E$ such that $a\cal R b,$ then you also have $b\cal Ra.$ Hence, when you state

> Because of the reflexive nature of $\cal R$
> $y\cal R x \implies x \mathcal R y$

you are making a mistake. You are using the symmetry property and not the reflexivity property. Everything besides this is okay. You could spare some words, like **lulu** suggested in the comments.